# How to send more than 1gig of email attachment

Tags: email

We need a webhost server that can handle of sending and receiving huge amount of POP3 emails around 500MB to 1Gig. Is there site capable of this? Or is this possible if we will setup a 24/7 PC linux server and install postfix?

Thanks,

Comment: You DO NOT send files this big through email.  There are multiple good reasons why this is the case.

Comment: In the good old days, we had utilities to split attachments into multiple pieces so we didn't kill the system like a 1G attachment would. Due to encoding bloat, that 1G will require 1.6G of SMPT friendly Mime64 or equivalent printable text to transfer. SMTP doesn't transmit binary, but ASCII encoded MIME attachments. There are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not only the host you have your domain at. You might configure your server to 500MB+, but the rest of the world doesnt.
An email bounces through various servers (when not SSL-ing) before it ends up at the reciever, 500MB+ doesn't *bounce* very well, with an very high chance the first server will do 'nope'.

I suggest:
- you find a (cheap) hosting and send a downloadlink to the file*
- You use something like [wetransfer.com](https://www.wetransfer.com/) (is a userfriendly 'downloadlink' system, up to 2GB)
- Use something like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) to sync files between users.

**Use a downloadscript to send chuncks of data to the user, otherwise people will have to wait forever before the [you want to download this]-dialog even pops up with these filesizes.*

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the suggestion. We are hosted in Dreamhost, but the server cannot send more than 40MB of email attachments.
How do I send more than 500MB without using FTP? My boss is not that techie, hates using Yousendit or Sendspace..

Comment: Editted my topic. Don't think you have other options available. Sending via mail will **not** work.